# javax.microedition.lcdui does not exist

Tags: java-me

I am trying to learn j2me so I try a simple j2me app at netbeans but code can not find  javax.microedition.lcdui  package.I have install Java 1.8 with J2ME 
The project at netbeans has cldc 1.8 and MEEP 8.
The code can find javax.microedition.midlet,   lcdui does not exist anymore?

Comment: I download midp 2.1 and I fix the imports but now I have  this "it uses or overrides a deprecated API."midp is deprecated?There is any j2me book published  the last years?

Comment: J2ME isn't used only for MIDlets. It's also used for Xlets. My first thought was that maybe you'd installed the Xlet SDK version. But then you say that Netbeans does find `javax.microedition.midlet`, so I'm as puzzled as you.
I would try re-installing SDK and IDE and WTK etc.

Comment: I use java  8,at project properties I do not use midp but another package Micro Edition Embedded Profile (MEEP) .Maybe there are other similar packages that my old book does not talking about

Comment: I have no experience with MEEP (JSR361), but I know that to target JavaME MIDP2 enabled phones you should get JSR118 - or if you're going really oldschool; MIDP1 (JSR37).
I suspect MEEP is for Xlet development (like e.g. Blu-ray applications), not MIDlet development.

Comment: I google "gui JME" and I found this https://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/simple-gui-for-jme/35312

Comment: Start here: https://netbeans.org/kb/73/javame/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem too. The reason is because java me sdk uses micro edition and embedded profile(meep) and the lcdui class is a part of midp. Any app created on an meep profile using lcdui class is denied by the compiler. The possible solution is downloading the wtk. It includes the midp profile and lcdui class